# React, HTML and JavaScript: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my React app I am getting the following error: "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops". I changed the state once the for loop is completed. I dont see what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

```
//React
class Pagination extends Component {
  state = {
    li: []
  }

  liTags = (pageNum) =>{
    return(  <li className="PageNumber" key={pageNum}><span>{pageNum}</span></li>)
  }

  pagincationScript = (totalPages, page) =>{
    let li = []

    for(let i = 1; i < totalPages; i++){
      li.push(this.liTags(i))

    }
    this.setState({
      li: li
    })

    if(page > 1 && page < totalPages){
    
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <li className="Btn Previous"><span><i>&#8592;</i>Previous</span></li>
          {this.state.li}
          <li className="Btn Previous"><span><i>&#8594;</i>Next</span></li>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Pagination">
        <ul>
          {this.pagincationScript(10,5)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PagePagination;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically causing a stack overflow.
You are calling a `setState` inside a render, but, because the `setState` dispatch another render, your code is causing an infinite loop.

You need to stop calling `this.setState` every render.
In your case, you don't **need** to put li inside the component's state, you can simply render `{li}`.

```
pagincationScript = (totalPages, page) => {
  let li = []

  for(let i = 1; i < totalPages; i++) {
    li.push(this.liTags(i))
  }

  if(page > 1 && page < totalPages) {

    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <li className="Btn Previous"><span><i>&#8592;</i>Previous</span></li>
          {li}
        <li className="Btn Previous"><span><i>&#8594;</i>Next</span></li>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

But, if you need it to be inside the state, you should move the code that populates `this.state.li` to a lifecycle method, like `componentDidUpdate` (or useEffect, if you are using hooks).

Answer (score 0):

Move your `liTags()` to inside the `paginationScript()` and store the `li` as a local variable. Keeping JSX in a React state is a really bad practice, never do that!